# avrdude and attiny2313 and avrisp

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, avrdude

I'm trying to program my ATTiny 2313 with avrdude. This is my command line and output (The first line is the command I entered, the others are the output):

```
utnmac:firmware utn$ make flash
avrdude -c avrispmkII -p attiny2313 -U flash:w:main.hex:i

avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.

make: *** [flash] Error 1
```

UPDATE: Seems to be a problem with my wiring but i can't find a good tutorial on where my wiring needs to go. Right now I'm using this:
[image: isp wiring]

Answer (score 1):

Is that the entirety of your circuit?

From the [online documentation](http://www.atmel.no/webdoc/avrispmkii/avrispmkii.intro_connecting.html),

> The AVRISP mkII does not provide power on the Vcc pin, but uses this pin to sense the voltage on the target circuitry. Your circuit needs to be powered by external means to operate.

You also need to pull reset to Vcc through a resistor so that it doesn't float when not activated.